# Bootstrap isotope and lazyload fetch/load images via json

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-lazyload

Normal isotope usage for ajax fetching is working.
see working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/mfNpH/)**.

isotope with lazyload via ajax fetch not working.
see problem [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/E7ZRW/).

**Problem:**
lazyload does not trigger and keeps showing grey image.

**javaScript for lazyload setup :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //
    // initialize at ready ;
    //
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
            return containerWidth / 12;
        },
        onLayout: function () {
            $win.trigger("scroll");
        }
    });
    //
    // here i will be using data through api
    // For now I am defining json manually
    // var json is defined at top of this code 
    // considering json return was success
    //$.getJSON(APIURL, function (json) {
    var newElements = "";
    $.each(json, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key);
        newElements +=
            '<div class="box">' +
            '<img class="lazy" src="' + small_img + '" data-originalsrc="' + value['image'] + '" width="' + value['width'] + '" height="' + value['height'] + '" />' +
            '</div>';
    });

    var $newElems = $(newElements);

    $container.append($newElems).imagesLoaded(function () {

        $container.isotope('appended', $newElems);

        $imgs.lazyload({
            container: $container,
            effect: "fadeIn",

        }).removeClass("lazy");
        $imgs.trigger('scroll');


    });
    //});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/E7ZRW/17/)

**Issues that were causing failure:**

1. **Bootstrap** I had to put style="width:XX;height:XX" in image tag too along with normal width and height parameter to overwrite bootstrap img{} css definitions which were one of problems. `<img class="lazy" width="200" height="300" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;" data-original="abc.jpg" src="lazygrey.gif">`
2. **vars Before AJAX:** Since I am using ajax content so var defined like `var $imgs=  $("img.lazy");` before ajax call doesnot work. So to be safe I used $("img.lazy") directly.